# Why do we have both Eloquent and Query Builder in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Considering what they both do is overlapping, why does Laravel have both and not just one of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Eloquent adds a complexity layer that aren't always necessary. That complexity have it cost in performance that can be avoided when dealing with raw data.

The performance difference can reach 50% easily.

Fundamentally both are necessary because Eloquent extends and uses `QueryBuilder`.